# Saber si mi servidor php está en dev o en producción

Tags: php

¿Hay alguna librería o función para detectar si mi servidor está en producción o en dev?

Tengo cierto código que sólo me gustaría que se ejecutase en dev.

No me sirve saber si está en localhost de esta manera:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost') // or any other host
{
     // development
}

else
{
     // production
}
```

porque me gustaría ejecutarlo en dev para desarrollo en entornos de red local (192.168.X.X) para por ejemplo debug en dispositivos locales y testing, etc,

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar un fichero de configuración que contenga los diferentes valores entre dev y producción? El problema de usar las variables de `$_SERVER` es que no son del todo seguras porque algunas de ellas pueden ser _falseadas_ por el usuario.

Comment: Como te dice el compañero de arriba, puedes tener dos archivos de configuración, pero hasta donde sé, solo puedes usar uno. En la carpeta de php hay dos templates de archivos de configuración: php.ini-development y php.ini-production. Puedes usarlos como referencia y adaptarlos a tus necesidades.